# query underscore character with jq

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to get the `ActionId` and *not* "Status=OK" in the following JSON with jq.

I have tried the following query. but with no success:

```
jq '_source,.Status'
```

It doesn't work because `_source` contains the underscore character.

```json
[
  {
    "_index": "filebeat-7.2.0-2020.09.06-000060",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_version": 1,
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
      "@timestamp": "2020-09-09T11:34:21.192Z",
      "ActionName": "Service",
      "ConnectionId": "53NCBP",
      "Method": "POST",
      "ActionId": "ecdc38f369e3",
      "stream": "stdout",
      "RequestId": "0HM2D6Q53NC1",
      "Status": "OK",
      "@t": "2020-09-09T11:34:21.1926712Z",
      "input": {
        "type": "docker"
      },
      "IP": "1.1.1.1" 
    },
    "fields": {
      "@timestamp": [
        "2020-09-09T11:34:21.192Z"
      ],
      "s.timestamp": [
        "2020-09-09T11:34:21.192Z"
      ]
    },
    "sort": [
      1599651261192
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Please show the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
jq ._source.ActionId
// returns:
// "ecdc38f369e3"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
cat so.json | jq ._source.Status
"OK"

cat so.json | jq ._source.ActionId
"ecdc38f369e3"
```

Comment: You can use `jq ._source[]` for entire list